# get the number of inputs given to a function js

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Assume i have created a function `function findInputGiven(){}` and i called it somewhere below twice `findInputGiven([1, 2], [3, 4])`, `findInputGiven([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6])`. This function can be called with multiple inputs, i dont know how many inputs will be available in my `findInputGiven` function. How can i get the number of inputs given to call function.

My task is to return an array of all numbers of given arrays. If the function is called like `findInputGiven([1, 2], [5, 6])`, then i should return `[1, 2, 5, 6]`.

Comment: Every function is provided with an [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object that has a length property. Use it within the function itself.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to get the number of arguments or combine and return the arrays?

Comment: Do you want something similar to ruby's function(*args)? (https://prnt.sc/xyddiy) Which can be call as function(1,2,3,4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My task is to return an array of all numbers of given arrays

What you can do is use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to get an array of all arguments and then return the [flattened](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) result. You can still get a count of the arguments if required but for this task, I don't think you'll need it.

```js
function findInputGiven(...arrays) {
  // you can get the argument count if you need it
  console.log(`Got ${arrays.length} argument(s)`)

  // return the flattened result
  return arrays.flat()
}

console.info(findInputGiven([1, 2], [3, 4]))
console.info(findInputGiven([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important }
```

Comment: Thank you. I found your answer very useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with [`Rest parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) of ES6 feature along with don't want to `"transpile" your code`.

You can achieve it by using `arguments`.

```js
function findInputGiven() {
  const numberOfInputs = arguments.length;
  console.log(`Number of inputs: ${numberOfInputs}`);
  
  let result = [];
  Object.values(arguments).forEach(function(item, index){
    if(Array.isArray(item))
      result = result.concat(item);
    else
      result.push(item);
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(findInputGiven([1, 2], [3, 4]))
console.log(findInputGiven([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], 7))
```

---

**More detailed explanation:**

As you may know, [`rest parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#browser_compatibility) & [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#browser_compatibility) aren't supporting IE. So that is where `transpiler` come from :)
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by _"don't want to "transpile" your code"_?

Comment: @Phil Oh, As you may know, [`rest parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#browser_compatibility) & [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#browser_compatibility) aren't supporting IE. So that is where `transpiler` come from :)

Comment: Nothing supports IE, not even Microsoft. FYI, [IE does not support `Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#browser_compatibility) either